# HTML pattern not working when form submitted

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Case 1**

I have the following which works as expected. When the "button" is clicked, the form is submitted and the pattern is validated.

```
<input autocomplete="off" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$"
        type="text" id="username" name="username" required class="form-control"
        value="${loginForm.username}" placeholder="Email"/>

<button type="submit" id="submitButton" name="forgotUsernameBtn" class="submit butn-blue butn-md butn">
    Forgot Username
</button>
```

**Case 2**

However, I have a different case where I need to first call a function (`verifyCaptcha()`), and then submit the form, and in this case the pattern validation on the email is not occurring.

```
function verifyCaptcha(){
    console.log('verifying captcha');
    if (typeof grecaptcha !== 'undefined') {
        var siteKey = 'xxxx';
        grecaptcha.execute(siteKey, {action: 'forgotPassword'}).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $('#response').val(response);
            $('#loginFormBean').submit();
        });
    }
    return false;
}

<button type="button" id="submitButton"  value="Submit" class="submit butn butn-blue butn-md" onclick="verifyCaptcha()">Submit</button>
```

This is because in **Case1** it is submitted via a `button type="submit"` and in **Case2** is is only submitted in the function via Jquery `$('#loginFormBean').submit();`.

**Question**

Is it possible to get **Case2** to perform the pattern validation?

Comment: You have yo manually validate your form when using Ajax. So answer is _Yes, it's possible_

Comment: @Justinas I don't see any AJAX involved here?

Comment: FYI: `return false;` - that's not actually achieving anything in this situation. To prevent the normal form submission, you would need `onclick="return verifyCaptcha()">` in this situation.

Comment: It is only doing client side validation (on `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$"`), so there is no AJAX.  I would like HTML `pattern` to check the email in Case2 like it does in Case1.

Comment: You can trigger form validation via JS, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#the_constraint_validation_api

Comment: Ideally you should use `type="email"` and have all this inside a `form` element, that way you can call methods such as `.reportValidity()` and `.checkValidity()` on the form element and it will validate accordingly and provide user feedback (all powered by the browser), you may also need `requred` on the `input` to do the above

Comment: @Harrison I thought that your suggestion to change to `type="email"` would work, but it doesn't validate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55039024/html5-pattern-validation-not-working-when-submitting-form-through-onsubmit-attri

Comment: @Richard like I said, and the link you provided also says, you need to call the valid checking methods yourself, (`reportValidity` and `checkValidity`), the input may also need `requried` as an empty input could be considered valid

Comment: Have you tried `$('#submitButton').click()` instead of `$('#loginFormBean').submit();`?

Comment: As @Harrison mentioned, your `pattern=` looks like it's trying to validate an email address, but I guarantee you that you will be excluding valid email addresses. `@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+` alone will exclude valid domains that are not strictly ASCII. For your comment "but it doesn't validate" you should give details - what test email did you use that didn't validate?
I'm commenting, not answering, because `.checkValidity()` and `.reportValidity()` are the way to go for your actual question; this email match is a side issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have an event listener for the submit event on the form. This event will only happen if all the form fields are valid. The callback function of the event listener is defined as `async` and has a `e.preventDefault()` to stop the form from submitting. And now I can use `await` in front of the function call `grecaptcha.execute()`. The response of the function call will return eventually (here I fake 2 seconds) and the script continues. If the response is OK I call `e.target.submit()` for "resuming" the submit.

The default behavior of my fake module is to return `true`. So, the example will always submit when the form is valid.

```js
// fake module to for testing
// change "true" to "false" to let the captcha fail.
const grecaptcha = (() => {
  return {
    async execute(key, obj) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {resolve(true);}, 2000);
    });
    }
  }
})();

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', async e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (typeof grecaptcha !== 'undefined') {
    let siteKey = 'xxxx';
    let validCaptcha = await grecaptcha.execute(siteKey, {
      action: 'forgotPassword'
    });
    console.log(validCaptcha);
    if(validCaptcha){
      console.log('Submitting...');
      e.target.submit();
    }else{
      console.log('Captcha not ok');
    }
  } else {
    console.log('No grecaptcha');
  }
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <input autocomplete="off" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$" type="text" id="username" name="username" required class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Email" />
  <input name="captchaok" type="hidden" value="false" pattern="true" required/>
  <button type="submit" id="submitButton" class="submit butn butn-blue butn-md">Submit</button>
</form>
```